# MobileFirst Adapter - FWLSE0152E: Unable to find certificate chain with alias: 'mydomain.com' for HTTPS protocol

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have followed the steps as mentioned in below url :

[Configuring SSL between MobileFirst adapters & back-end servers by using self-signed certificates.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html?lang=en)

After performing above steps, I am able to see the certificate in key store with correct alias name 'mydomain.com'. However, when I try to invoke the procedure which has defined in HTTP adapter to make a call to back end server using HTTPS, below exception has thrown in worklight server console.

```
FWLSE0152E: Unable to find certificate chain with alias: 'mydomain.com'
```

Could you please provide any suggestions which would help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the CN of your backend server is not equals to backend domain name that you defined in the adapter xml file.
If the CN=mydomain.com try to export public certificate from backend keystore and import it into adapter's keystore using open ssl library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both are same, let me give the complete details.

Comment: Actually both are same (used IP Address insted domain)and below are the steps followed 1. Created certificate in back end server with alias 192.168.134.61 and keystore as 192.168.134.61.keystore 2.Added configuration in backend server.xml   <Connector port="443"..... keystoreFile="192.168.134.61.keystore" keystorePass="passw0rd" keystoreType="JKS" keyAlias="192.168.134.61"/> 3. Added domain (192.168.134.61), ssl Alias(192.168.134.61) and ssl password in adapter.xml 4. Exported certificate from back end server (192.168.134.61.crt) 5.Imported certificate to worklight server/conf/default.keystore

Comment: So strange that the server tries to get the certificate with alias 'mydomain.com'. Where this alias is configured?

Comment: Here is an example of generation self signed certificate for backend server pavel.com:

>keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
**What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  pavel.com**
...
Is **CN=pavel.com**, OU=none, O=none, L=none, ST=none, C=none correct?
... Note that CN name is the domain name or IP of backend that you configure in the adapter xml file.